# Updating master branch within fork

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a fork of my team project and I have code that is not yet deployable but I have to move on for the time being with the current changes in master so I can complete the next iteration of my sprint. I have checked out a branch from master and so my code is in another branch and is in master.

I want to reset the master in my fork to the latest changes from the deployable master. I essentially do the following and recieve the corresponding output:

```
git branch
  Other_Branch
  *master

git remote add upstream url/toRepoOnGitHub
   fatal: remote upstream already exists

git fetch upstream
  fatal: 'url/to/original/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

I recently learned about branching and that is my workflow now but I would like to know how to resolve this out of curiosity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the remote repository doesn't exist or you have added the wrong one.

My suggestion first remove the origin and re-add it:

```
git remote remove upstream
git remote add upstream https://github.com/username/repository
```